# Django change choice before validation

Tags: django

I am trying to update a choice field before it is validated in Django. The reason for this is the choice field in question value is the Id of a model that i want to update.

```
def fuelLogSystemOne(request):
entries = FuelLogSystemOneMod.objects.all().order_by('date')
products = productsMod.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.AddFuelLogOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    productid = form['product'].value()
    product = productsMod.objects.get(id=productid)
    product_id = request.POST.get('product')
    form.fields['product'].choices = [(product.product_type, product.product_type)]
    if form.is_valid():
        bucketsRemoved = form['buckets_added'].value()
        product.stock -= bucketsRemoved
        product.save(['stock'])
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.staff = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = forms.AddFuelLogOneForm()
return render(request,'systems/fuellogsystemone.html',{'form':form,'entry':entries,'products':products})
```

The below part is where i am trying to change the form data before it gets validated so it doesn't say 'Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices'

```
    product_id = request.POST.get('product')
    form.fields['product'].choices = [(product.product_type, product.product_type)]
```

But when I first submit the form it is still saying 'Select a valid choice.'

At what point does Django validate the form because I am changing the form before the is_valid() method and it still hits this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be in your form, you have to override the init method, and pass the product id during form initialization in the views

**forms.py**

```
class AddFuelLogOneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop('product', None)
        self.fields['product'].choices = [(product.product_type, product.product_type)]
```

**views.py**

```
def fuelLogSystemOne(request):
    entries = FuelLogSystemOneMod.objects.all().order_by('date')
    products = productsMod.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST.get('product')
        productid = form['product'].value()
        product = productsMod.objects.get(id=productid)
        product_id = request.POST.get('product')
        form = forms.AddFuelLogOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES, product=product)
        if form.is_valid():
            bucketsRemoved = form['buckets_added'].value()
            product.stock -= bucketsRemoved
            product.save(['stock'])
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.staff = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = forms.AddFuelLogOneForm()
    return render(request,'systems/fuellogsystemone.html',{'form':form,'entry':entries,'products':products})
```

Comment: When I tried this i got the error that product was a None type and couldn't retrieve product_type from the forms.py file. This is a learning project in Django for me so still trying to get my head round a few things, is the idea that on line `form = forms.AddFuelLogOneForm(request.POST, request.FILES, product=product)` you are passing the objects to the form? Should the model productsMod be imported on the forms.py for when the request isn't a POST?

Comment: yes, you have to import the products model in the forms.py file